# getting headers value in proxygen

Tags: c++, http-headers

i am using the proxygen for making a simple web server. i am restricted to use proxygen.I am using proxygen default echo server example i want to print the header values whenever a request is sent to the server. below is the code that i think i should modify.but what exactly i am unsure of.:

```
#include "customHandler.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <proxygen/httpserver/RequestHandler.h>
#include <proxygen/httpserver/ResponseBuilder.h>
#include <proxygen/lib/http/HTTPMessage.h>
#include <proxygen/lib/http/HTTPMethod.h>
using namespace std;
using namespace proxygen;

namespace EchoService {
EchoHandler::EchoHandler(EchoStats* stats): stats_(stats) {
}

void EchoHandler::onRequest(std::unique_ptr<HTTPMessage> headers) noexcept {
  //------------------HERE TO MODIFY I THINK-------------------//

}

void EchoHandler::onBody(std::unique_ptr<folly::IOBuf> body) noexcept {
  if (body_) {
    body_->prependChain(std::move(body));
  } else {
    body_ = std::move(body);
  }
}
/*
.header("Request-Number",
            //this sets the request number
            folly::to<std::string>(stats_->getRequestCount()),"test-b")*/

void EchoHandler::onEOM() noexcept {
  ResponseBuilder(downstream_)
    .status(200, "OK")

    //Response is set Here...........ex-> .body(std::move("some Response object"))
    .body(std::move(body_))
    .sendWithEOM();
}

void EchoHandler::onUpgrade(UpgradeProtocol protocol) noexcept {
  // handler doesn't support upgrades
}

void EchoHandler::requestComplete() noexcept {
  delete this;
}

void EchoHandler::onError(ProxygenError err) noexcept {
  delete this;
}

}
```

correct me if i am wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
void EchoHandler::onRequest(std::unique_ptr<HTTPMessage> headers) noexcept
{   
    HTTPHeaders head = headers->getHeaders();
    head.forEach([&] (const string& header, const string& val) {
          cout << header << ": " << val<<endl;
    });
}
```